# Beamer Overlay for the "description" of the "item label"

Tags: beamer, overlays, description, pause

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%remove navigation 
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{booktabs, textcomp}  % Tables
\usepackage{tabularx,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}      % Diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{url}       % `\url`s
\usepackage{listings}  % Code listings
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{graphics}
\title{Chronic diarrhea: a case based Approach} 
\author{Dr }
\date {\today}
\institute{My Hospital }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Terminologies/ definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Diarrhea] 
    \item [Acute diarrhea]
    \item [persistent diarrhea]
    \item [Chronic diarrhea]
\end{description}
\end{frame}
%---
\begin{frame} {Terminologies/ definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Diarrhea] Increase in the fluidity / frequency of stool 
    \item [Acute diarrhea] $\leq$ 2 weeks 
    \item [Persistent diarrhea] 2 to 4 weeks 
    \item [Chronic diarrhea] $\geq $4 weeks 
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Hi 
This is the mwe of beamer presentation I am preparing. I want the item label for the description to appear first and then in a next slide description should appear. I achieved it crudely by duplicating a slide. But there must be a better way. 
Kindly help

Comment: Have you tried with the `\only{}` command ?

Comment: Jerome@ Please elaborate

Comment: try `\item [Diarrhea] \only<2>{Increase in the fluidity / frequency of stool}`

Comment: Just try the example given by @samcarter

Comment: So, what happened?

Comment: @samcarter was helpful too, that's why I voted up on his comment.

Answer (score 3):

Like @samcarter said, you have to put your definitions as an argument of the `only` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Chronic diarrhea: a case based Approach} 
\author{Dr }
\date {\today}
\institute{My Hospital }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame} {Terminologies/ definitions}
\begin{description}[Persistent diarrhea]
%% Persistent diarrhea is the longest item. 
%% We add it as an option of the *description* environment 
%%    to have all the items aligned on the right.
    \item [Diarrhea] \only<2>{Increase in the fluidity / frequency of stool }
    \item [Acute diarrhea] \only<2>{$\leq$ 2 weeks }
    \item [Persistent diarrhea] \only<2>{2 to 4 weeks }
    \item [Chronic diarrhea] \only<2>{$\geq $4 weeks }
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can find documentation on the `only` command on [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#Text_animations).

By the way, the given example in your original post was not an MWE because a lot of packages are charged and useless here.

Comment: Suggestion: add `[Persistent diarrhea]` as option just after `\begin{description}`...

Comment: Sure. If you want the items to be right aligned (which is more beautiful).
I'll change my answer taking into account your suggestion.
Thank's @PaulGaborit